# Using Firebase for Database Cloud + Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am a new user for Firebase console. I don't know from where to start to use the real-time database. I have read the documentation in the Firebase website, but I am still having doubts about it. I also searched and what I have seen is all about how to check the authority of the user and read/write from the database.

How will I use the SQLite database which is in the Android and link it to the JSON object in Firebase? Or do I need to create the SQLite in Android?

Thank you

Comment: Why would you have an SQLite database locally if you plan to use the firebase database?

Comment: Yes that's what I' m confused about it. So, how can I create my database by using the fire base only?

Comment: By not adding a sqlite database? I don't think I understand the problem

Comment: See, I want to use the feature of the real time database in fire base but I don't know from where to start ?

Comment: You probably want to read the documentation on how to get started